# Select2 keep showing "Searching" in ajax with pivot (n-n) in Laravel Backpack 5 Pro

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I have 2 models: Order and Product, each has belongsToMany with pivot set properly.

In OrderCrudController, I also use FetchOperation and make a fethProducts() function as below:

```
use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\FetchOperation;

public function fetchProducts()
{
    return $this->fetch([
        'model' => \App\Models\Product::class,
        'searchable_attributes' => ['name','sku']
    ]);
    // return $this->fetch(\App\Models\Product::class); <-- I also tried this one
}

protected function setupCreateOperation()
{
    CRUD::setValidation(OrderRequest::class);
    
    // other fields

    $this->crud->addField([
        'name' => 'products',
        'type' => 'relationship',
        'pivotSelect' => [
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'ajax'      => true,
        ],
        'subfields' => [
            [
                'name' => 'quantity',
                'type' => 'number',
            ],
        ],
    ]);
}
```

But it comes to unexpected behavior when I search the product, the select2 field remains "searching" though the request successfully retrieved the data.

[screenshot - select2 field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRIu8.png)

[screenshot - ajax results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQbwC.png)

PS: this field works perfectly without subfields, no vendor overrides etc., so I think I've set everything correctly.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

This was asked two months ago but somehow I missed it, just noticed it today after someone opened an issue on the GitHub repository.

I am happy you guys found a solution for it but unfortunatelly I cannot recommend it as using the select2_from_ajax will miss the functionality to don't allow the selection of the same pivots twice, otherwise you will have undesired consequences when saving the entry.

I've just submitted a PR to fix this issue, I will ping you guys here when it's merged, probably by next Monday.

Cheers

Comment: Just to let you guys know that the fix is merged and tagged and a composer update will pull the fix for you. The issue was tracked here: https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/4437

Answer (score 0):

I just came accross this exact problem and after quite some research and trials, i finally found a solution !

The problem seems to be related to the `relationship` field type inside the pivotSelect. Try to use `select2_from_ajax` instead and don't forget to set method to POST explicitly, that worked for me like a charm.

Here is what you might try in your case :

```
$this->crud->addField([
    'name' => 'products',
    'type' => 'relationship',
    'pivotSelect' => [
        'attribute' => 'name',
        'type'      => 'select2_from_ajax',
        'method'    => 'POST',
        'data_source' => backpack_url('order/fetch/products') // Assuming this is the URL of the fetch operation
    ],
    'subfields' => [
        [
            'name' => 'quantity',
            'type' => 'number',
        ],
    ],
]);
```